# Adding Excel file with degrees to map with CRS in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, excel

How can I add a layer with X,Y in degrees (from an excelfile) to a map with CRS?

I am using QGIS 2.8.2

Comment: give an example of what your X,Y looks like in Excel... if they're already in decimal degrees, you can save your Excel to a CSV and add it easily...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your coordinates are in decimal degrees (see the answer of HeyOverThere), you just have to export your Excel file as a CSV and import the CSV following [this tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html). You may need to reproject your layer depending on its original datum.

Answer (score 0):

If the coordinates are in degrees, minutes, and seconds you'll need to convert those values to decimal.  Here's a quick guide on how to do that:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171220131717/http://mathforum.org/sarah/hamilton/ham.degrees.html)

Comment: Look at this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41962/how-to-import-coordinate-data-from-excel-into-qgis/41967#41967