# How to add point features from longitude and latitude coordinates on QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude

[image: Screenshot of the coordinates]
Will it be possible to add a set of points from a table of longitude and latitude coordinates as show in the pic attached? Or will I have to convert them to X Y coordinates and then add it as a .CSV layer? if this is the case how do I go about the conversion.

Comment: This may help you https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41962/importing-coordinate-data-from-excel-into-qgis/41967#41967 .As you can notice data is in decimal degrees, in order to convert your data you must do as follows deg+(min/60)+(sec/3600). If your data is on west longitude or south latitude you have to multiply the result of the formula times-1

Answer (score 2):

Adding it as a CSV would be my choice, there's a function for importing csv with long-lat columns (the comma that appears together with the import vector, raster, etc icons; these must be, as mentioned, in decimal degrees, you may use a spreadsheet formula with

```
=left(b2,1)+(mid(b2,3,2)/60)+ (mid(b2,6,3)/3600)
```