# Importing Excel into QGIS as layer and not as attribute table

Tags: qgis, import

I'm trying to add Excel sheet as a point layer, that includes coordinates into QGIS.

Instead of a shapefile, it comes as attribute table (layer name is shown and attribute table logo beside it instead of point layer) and the layer doesn't appear in the canvas. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your first row of data and the header row, as well as the parameters you use when loading the csv.

Comment: Please check these topics [Importing Spreadsheets or CSV files](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html), [Importing coordinate data from excel into QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41962/importing-coordinate-data-from-excel-into-qgis) or [How to import spreadsheet data into QGIS](https://www.hatarilabs.com/ih-en/how-to-import-spreadsheet-data-into-qgis).

Answer (score 1):

You would have to save your Excel sheet as a CSV file. That file can be imported in QGIS (layers -> add layer-> add comma separated value layer). Once you do that, a screen should pop up where you can set your x- and y-coordinates among other settings.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong, it's just that an excel file IS an (attribute) table, it doesn't contain any geometry, if you want to display it as point you have to use one steep more to tell QGIS what attributes needs to be converted to geometry.

The first way of doing this is to convert your Excel to CSV as when adding a SCV you could specify geometry column, if you can't/dont want to convert your Excel file to CSV you could import it as a table (as you already did) and use the "Create Point Layer From Table" tool (you'll find it in the Processing Toolbox, in the Vector creation group)

[image]