# Merging attributes of point features at same location

Tags: qgis, point, grouping

I have a CSV-file with all the facilities in an area, some sites have multiple facilities so at some locations there will be multiple points e.g. sports hall and swimming pool.

Is there a way to join all the points at one location (they have a unique ID) but retain the information so that if I click on the point it will show that there is a sports hall and a swimming pool not two points one for sports hall and one for swimming pool?

Answer (score 3):

It is expected that you have already imported your CSV file into QGIS and possess a basic point vector layer, for more details check references.

In QGIS I can suggest using a [**"Virtual Layer"**](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let's assume there is one point layer `'points'` (3 features at the same location) with its corresponding attribute table, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible *to join all the points at one location (they have a unique ID) but retain the information.*

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT geometry,
       GROUP_CONCAT("id") AS ids,
       GROUP_CONCAT("Name") AS Names,
       COUNT(geometry) AS Patloc
FROM "points"
GROUP BY geometry
```

*where*

- `"Patloc"` is a number of points at one location.

The output Virtual Layer will look like

[image: result]

---

**References:**

- [QGIS Tutorials and Tips | Importing Spreadsheets or CSV files (QGIS 3)](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html)
- [Importing coordinate data from excel into QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41962/importing-coordinate-data-from-excel-into-qgis)
- [How to import spreadsheet data into QGIS](https://www.hatarilabs.com/ih-en/how-to-import-spreadsheet-data-into-qgis)

Comment: I seem to be having an issue with the virtual layer using the following query
SELECT DISTINCT geometry,
       GROUP_CONCAT(Site Id) AS Ids,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Site Name) AS Name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Facility Type) AS Facility,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Facility Sub Type) AS SubTypes,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Unit) AS Units,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Number) AS Numbers,
       COUNT() AS Pactloc
FROM "points"
GROUP BY geometry

When I test I get the execution error: 1 - near "Id": syntax error
I can't work out where I have gone wrong, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? What does your data look like ?

Comment: When I test I get the following:
Query execution error on CREATE TEMP VIEW _tview AS SELECT DISTINCT geometry,
       GROUP_CONCAT(Site Id) AS Ids,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Site Name) AS Name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Facility Type) AS Facility,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Facility Sub Type) AS SubTypes,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Unit) AS Units,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Number) AS Numbers,
       COUNT() AS Pactloc
FROM "points"
GROUP BY geometry: 1 - near "Id": syntax error

Comment: Put your fields in “”, e.g. “Site id“

Comment: I then get: Referenced table points in query not found!
I have added the CSV with the points already and tried  importing it to the embedded layers, the error is present whether the CSV is imported or not

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume there is one point layer `"points"` (3 features at the same location) with its corresponding attribute table, see image below.

[image: input]

**Step 1.** In the Field Calculator create a new attribute, e.g. `"Names"` and fill it using the following expression

```py
concatenate("Name", group_by:=geom_to_wkt($geometry), concatenator:=', ')
```

[image: step_1]

**Step 2.** Apply `"Delete duplicate geometries"`.

[image: step_2]

**Step 3.** Delete irrelevant fields or add new fields.

[image: step_3]