# Importing CSV data from ACLED in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, csv, import

I have conflict data from ACLED. The data is in CSV format. Given the nature of the data (image attached), when I am selecting the CSV option while importing the file in QGIS via "open data manager", `"X"` and `"Y"` fields do not appear as longitude and latitude respectively.

The heading of the first column in the CSV file rather appears in the `"X"` and `"Y"` fields. However, if I select the option Custom delimiters and then semicolon (I deselect the option tab), then the problem gets sorted out. `"X"` field is then longitude and `"Y"` is latitude

[image].

Am I doing the right thing? I want to avoid problems appearing later.

Comment: Have you checked this question [Importing coordinate data from excel into QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/41962/63384)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing it just right. In the Data Source Manger you can also select the fields for X and Y directly in the geometry definition.[image: QGIS Geomentry Definition]